# How to load .vimrc that is deleted and stored in memory

Tags: unix, vim, macvim

I have a question. Accidentally I removed my .vimrc file but macvim is still open and all the settings are stored. Is there a way to load it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for http://vi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It might fit better there, but that doesn't make it off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used it myself, but you could give the `mkexrc` command a try.

```
                                                          :mk :mkexrc              
  :mk[exrc] [file]        Write current key mappings and changed options to   
                          [file] (default ".exrc" in the current directory),
                          unless it already exists.
```

If you use plugins, you might want to look at your plugin manager's documentation to see if you can get a list of loaded plugin, which would get you halfway to recreating your plugin list.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to restore perfect copy of `.vimrc` only using running vim, I do not know the answer. If your question is how to restore most of your lost `.vimrc`, please consider following options:

But, firstly, look at the trash :-) (quite obvious, it is not the case, is it?)

There should be also `.gvimrc` in your home directory. Usually people share the same settings between terminal and graphic versions of macvim, with maybe some minor exceptions, like the size of the window etc. So, if you have `.gvimrc` you can most probably restore your `.vimrc`.

The other option can be examining your command history using `q:` command. If you tried commands before you put them to `.vimrc` and the history is long enough, you can copy&paste them and thus restore `.vimrc`.